# Loading datagrid itemsSource with SQL Server table under some condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am loading my datagrid in that way:

```
 myDataGrid.ItemsSource = _db.Products.ToList();
 datagrid = myDataGrid;
```

Where `_db.Products` is a table from my database. I want to create function which will get data from table `Products`, but with some condition. e.g `where category="meat"`.

How could I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use assign the entire collection as the itemsource and then filter the collection view.

Or you can use linq to create a new filtered list.

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = _db.Products.Where(product => product.Category == "meat").ToList();
```